# How to get the POST data (from external server to Angularjs) using angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, form-data

My question is about how to access the post data coming in to my AngularJs application.

On entering the url: **http://uat-login.testApplication.com** (assume this is third party application w.r.t my application), this test application send a response which post a request to my application say **http://172.12.12.100:8080/myApplication** with **form data: ResponseString : "sample response"**.

Lets say i have myapplicationMain.js file which has the controller called "mainController".  I would like to parse the Form data coming to my application in  mainController.  Please let me know how to achieve this in angularjs.

Comment: Is http://172.12.12.100:8080/myApplication a backend application like a simple REST app or is this your url to your local angularjs app?

Comment: it is my angularJS application, which has the main Controller.

Comment: You can't post data to your app with HTTP directly. You can use [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) to periodically get data from a server or you can use [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to make bidirectional stream between server and client.